# Image plotting - after processing

Tags: keras

I am studying the Keras package for deep learning, and found a nice code example on https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py that nicely integrates image pre-processing (e.g. rotations and shifts). I was wondering - is there an easy to plot the training images after pre-processing to observe the impact of these rotations and shifts?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the generated images to the disk by giving `save_to_dir='path_to_dir'` to the `flow()` function of the data generator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to plot images. For example in case of MNIST dataset:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from matplotlib import pyplot

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True)

datagen.fit(X_train)

for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=9):
# grid of 3x3 images
    for i in range(0, 9):
        pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
        pyplot.imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))

    pyplot.show()
    break
```

For more details refer [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/image-augmentation-deep-learning-keras/) link.